# Best way to create reusable objects like Fonts using C#

Tags: c#

I have an application where I am creating user controls and for that I have defined a class to reuse some fonts which looks like this:

```
public sealed class MyFonts
{       
    private static Font Tahoma7Regular = new Font("Tahoma", 7, FontStyle.Regular);
    private static Font Tahoma9Regular = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
    private static Font Tahoma9Bold = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold);       

    public static Font ChannelText = new Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle.Bold);       
    public static Font ClockText = Tahoma7Regular;
    public static Font HelpText = Tahoma9Regular;       
    public static Font RollFieldText = Tahoma9Bold;      

}
```

Is there any way to improve it, I saw `Brushes` class in a decompiler tool and they use something called `ThreadData` which I don't know, but just for simplicity can I also improve this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Before you create these many objects, analyse if you really need it? Most of the controls have  a Font property (which has the default value). You just need to set the values there rather than creating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadData sounds like some form of mechanism to share data between threads.

Take a look at the Brushes class:

```
public static Brush MediumAquamarine { get; }
```

Maybe tweak your class a little to become more like the above. Look's cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a usercontrol, then you shouldn't use static fields. The primary goal of a usercontrol is to be reusable, so you don't want to use fixed values for properties like font; those properties will be set by the usercontrol parent.

So what you might want to write are properties (using attributes such as `Description` is also useful):

```
[Category("Appearance"), Description("Gets or sets the text channel font.")]
[Browsable(true)]
public Font ChannelFont { get; set; }

[Category("Appearance"), Description("Gets or sets the text clock font.")]
[Browsable(true)]
public Font ClockFont { get; set; }
...
```